# Determine the polar form of $\sin\theta + i(1+ \cos\theta)$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Suppose that $0 \le \theta \lt 2\pi$. Determine the polar form of the following complex numbers: $$z = \sin\theta + i(1+ \cos\theta)$$
$$w = \cos\theta + \sin\theta +i(\sin\theta - \cos\theta)$$

The polar form of a complex number is given by $$x = |x|(\cos \theta +i\sin \theta)$$
I tried solving it with $(b/a) = \tan\theta$ but it yields an awkward result.

From $z$ I got $|z|=2\cos(\theta/2)$ which is not bad but when I tried to get the argument of $z$, looks like I’m missing some identity or something. $$\tan \phi = \frac{1 +\cos\theta}{sin\theta}$$
I did tried with the identity of the half angle tangent, but was not the same, I think.

Happens almost the same with $w$.

Note: $|w| =2 ^ {1/2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for $z$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos(\theta)=2 \cos^2(\theta/2)-1 \\
\sin(\theta) = 2 \sin(\theta/2) \cos(\theta/2).
\end{eqnarray*}
Hint for $w$: Use the $\cos$ and $\sin$ addition formulae and
\begin{eqnarray*}
w &=& \cos \theta + \sin \theta +i(\sin \theta - \cos \theta) \\ &=&\sqrt{2} \left( \cos(\theta) \cos(\pi/4) + \sin(\theta) \sin(\pi/4) \\+i( \sin(\theta) \cos(\pi/4) - \cos(\theta) \sin(\pi/4)) \right). 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Do you know where could I find those identities?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricAdditionFormulas.html

Comment: Thank you Donald.

Answer (score 1):

I have used $$1+\cos \theta =2\cos ^2 (\theta/2)$$
along with the usual angle addition formula to get $$z= \sin \theta +i(1+\cos \theta)$$

$$ |z|=2\cos(\theta/2)$$  and $$ arg (z) = ( \pi/2 -\theta /2)$$

Also for $w$ we have 
$$w=\cos (\theta) + \sin ( \theta ) +i(\sin (\theta) - \cos( \theta ))$$

$$|w| = \sqrt 2$$

$$ arg(w) = \theta -\pi/4$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Mohammad. I’m sorry but according to the hint given by Donald Splutterwit, I got this $arg(z) = \cot^2 (\theta/2)$, may be is the reason you have that argument. Could you help me understand your result?

Comment: @OctavioBerlanga let $ \alpha=arg(z)$ we have $\cos( \alpha) = \frac {\sin \theta }{2\cos (\theta /2)}= \sin(\theta /2)$ and $\sin \alpha = \frac {1+\cos \theta }{2\cos (\theta /2)} = \cos (\theta /2)$ hence $\alpha =( \pi/2-\theta /2)$

Comment: Thank you @Mohammad